# Declare map inside class with pointer to a (not yet) existing class as value?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to create a Chess game using a map and have a Chessboard class which stores it.

```
/* Headers and stuff */
class Piece;

Chessboard::Chessboard() {
  board["A1"] = new Piece*; /* Castle */
  board["B1"] = new Piece*; /* Knight */
  board["C1"] = new Piece*; /* Bishop */
  ...
```

After reading some answers here, I thought that by forward declaring Piece the compiler would let me create a map with key string and value Piece*. However, I get this error.

```
g++ -Wall -g -c chess.cpp
chess.cpp:19:15: error: assigning to 'mapped_type' (aka
'Piece*') from incompatible type 'Piece **'; dereference
with *
```

The header file where the Chessboard is is this:

```
// Header and stuff
class Piece;

class Chessboard {
public:
  Chessboard();
  ~Chessboard();
private:
  map<string, Piece*> board;
  map<string, Piece*>::iterator iterator;
}
```

How can I create map in Chessboard with pointer to Piece being it hasn't been created yet? Please keep the usage of map in the answer (even if it isn't the best option for Chess).

Comment: Replace new Piece*; with new Piece;

Comment: Your attempt is confusing.  Is what you commented out actual types derived from `Piece`?  All the answers so far assume they're not derived from `Piece`.  If they are derived from `Piece` please state this.

Comment: Life will go much easier for you if you don't use pointers or `new`

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that `new` produces a pointer to whatever the type you are creating. When you do this

```
new Piece*
```

the type is `Piece*`, so you get back a pointer to a pointer to `Piece`. To get a pointer to `Piece`, use

```
new Piece
```

instead.

**Note:** `map<string,Piece*>` is not the optimal data structure for representing a chess board. You would be better off with a 2D array of pointers to `Piece`, along with a scheme that maps labels of squares to `{row, column}` pairs:

```
array<array<Piece*,8>,8> board;
board[0][0] = new Piece;
```

Comment: and `delete` the pieces in a destructor

Answer (score 1):

No need for pointers or dynamic memory here. Just use automatic variables, i.e. change `board` to `map<string, Piece>`, and `iterator` accordingly.

Then you can insert default-constructed `Piece`s like so:

```
  board["A1"]; /* Castle */
  board["B1"]; /* Knight */
  board["C1"]; /* Bishop */
```

Then you don't need to define any destructor for your class either.

Comment: If you do this, moving a piece object from one cell to another becomes problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `new Piece*` calls, you'll get autoconstructed `Piece*` items in your map. If you don't include the header with actual definition of `Piece` class, you can't resolve the problem by switching `new Piece*` to `new Piece` (because it will require the full type defined at the point of call). Whenever and wherever you'll want to attach real `Piece`s to your pointers inside the map, you'll need to include the header, forward declaration won't be enough.